# TypeScript merge Function interface, extend Function prototype

Tags: javascript, function, typescript, ecmascript-6, prototype

```
interface Function {
    next(next: Function): Function;
    prev(prev: Function): Function;
}

Function.prototype.next = function(next) {
    const prev = this;
    return function() {
        return next.call(this, prev.apply(this, arguments));
    };
};

Function.prototype.prev = function(prev) {
    const next = this;
    return function() {
        return next.call(this, prev.apply(this, arguments));
    };
};

const f1 = function() { console.log("f1"); };
const f2 = () => console.log("f2");
const f3 = new Function("console.log('f3');");

f1.next(f2).next(f3)();
```

I wanted to do bad thing and extend Function prototype in TypeScript compiling to ES6. While this code works well in TypeScript Playground it fails in tsc 1.8.10 (Property `<<name>>` does not exist on type 'Function') because it can't merge with Function definition in [lib.es6.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts).

Any ideas how to do it properly?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/release-notes/typescript-1.8.html#augmenting-globalmodule-scope-from-modules):

> Similarly, the global scope can be augmented **from modules** using a `declare global` declaration.

Note the wording **from modules**. In other words, put the augmentations in a different module, and import it, which is when the merging occurs. Also, put the new prototype definitions in the same file.

```
// augment.ts
export {};

declare global {
  interface Function {
    next(next: Function): Function;
    prev(prev: Function): Function;
  }
}
Function.prototype.next = function(next) {
  const prev = this;
  return function() {
    return next.call(this, prev.apply(this, arguments));
  };
};
Function.prototype.prev = function(prev) {
  const next = this;
  return function() {
    return next.call(this, prev.apply(this, arguments));
  };
};


// test.ts
import './augment';

const f1 = function() { console.log("f1"); };
const f2 = () => console.log("f2");
const f3 = new Function("console.log('f3');");

f1.next(f2).next(f3)();
```

Output:

```
f1
f2
f3
```

Comment: Then tsc doesn't see methods like call and apply, basically everything that was declared in lib.es6.d.ts. I'd like to merge those definitions.

Comment: src/utils/Function.augment.ts(13,15): error TS2339: Property 'call' does not exist on type 'Function'.